# Как читать букву Е

Tags: орфоэпия

Пример:

```
1. веб-разработка   
   верба   
2. лень   
   сленг
```

————
Почему считается неверным однотипное произношение "Е"?
А вот если произносить "Е", как "Э", то считается верным. Как из миллиона сочетаний выделить, где "Е", а где "Э"?
И есть ли правило?

Comment: Напоминаю уважаемым коллегам, что ответы даются в ответах.

Comment: Это был комментарий.

Comment: @V.V., а какой он был, этот комментарий?

Comment: Э произносится , в основном, в заимствованиях из других языков. Проверить произношение можно по Орфоэпическому словарю под редакцией Аванесова.